# fourier decomposition of white noise

Tags: pr.probability, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I found in some lecture notes that Brownian motion is defined by its [Fourier series](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic815446.files/Fourier-Wiener.pdf):

$$ B(t) = \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z},\; m \neq 0} \frac{a_m}{m} e^{2\pi i \,mt} $$

Then I would get that its derivative is [white noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise):

$$ W(t) = \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z},\; m \neq 0} a_m e^{2\pi i \,mt} $$

What is the random Fourier series if we truncate it to the positive half?  Is there a name for that random process?

$$ f(t) = \sum_{ m \geq 0} a_m e^{2\pi i \,mt} $$

Here $a_m$ are standard [identical, independently distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables) Gaussian random variables with mean 0 and variance 1.

Comment: The series you wrote after "$B(t)=$" is a periodic function, and it is for such functions that Fourier series are defined.  But the usual Brownian motion (or Wiener process) is not periodic.

Comment: @MichaelHardy The [notes](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic815446.files/Fourier-Wiener.pdf) say $B(t) - b_0(t)$ is the Brownian motion.  The variance of Brownian motion is linear in the time $t$.  Then $B(0) = 0$, $B(t)$ is a.s. continuous, independent increments, and $B(t_2) - B(t_1)$ is normal.

Comment: @john : according to the notes (which have some confusing typos), brownian motion (starting at $0$) is given by $a_0t+B(t)-B(0)$ but only for $0\leq t\leq 1$.  Here $a_0$ is another standard gaussian.

Comment: @BS With independent increments, you could pick new Gaussian variables at t=1 and keep going.